# Laravel Where Clause keep increasing in foreach loop

Tags: php, database, laravel, eloquent

I have a sales table that store each sales of record per day, as user_id,quantity, revenue, sales_date. Now I want to get a monthly sales report from this sales table,

```js
 $months = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12];
       $sales = ArtistSale::query()->where('artist_id', $artist->id)
           ->whereYear('sales_date', $year);
           if($sales->exists()){
                foreach ($months as $month) {
                   $month_sales->put($month, $sale>whereMonth('sales_date',$month)>toSql());
                }
                return $month_sales;
            }
            return 'no sales for the year'
```

```html
       
     this is the query to get monthly reports
```

this results to `whereMonth` clause duplicating for each month[image]

Comment: Query builder will not return a new instance each time you do `whereSomething` but it will update the current instance and return that so doing `whereMonth` N times will add N month clauses one after the other. If you really want to make one query per month (you shouldn't need to) you need to create a new query each time.

Comment: please how you suggest i create the new query each time??

Comment: @apokryfos I have to make the query again per month `
                       ArtistSale::query()->where('artist_id', $artist_id)->whereYear('sales_date',$year)
                       ->whereMonth('sales_date', $month)->get()->sum('revenue')` in the for loop. Could you suggest if there is a better way to achieve this

Comment: you want get one sales reports or all sales ? i mean one artist_id or all artist ?

Comment: one artist for the month

Answer (score 2):

If you really need to do a query for each month then you need to create a new query object:

```
$months = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12];
$sales = ArtistSale::query()->where('artist_id', $artist->id)
       ->whereYear('sales_date', $year);
if($sales->exists()){
      foreach ($months as $month) {
          $newQuery = clone $sales;
          $month_sales->put($month, $newQuery->whereMonth('sales_date',$month)->toSql());
       }
       return $month_sales;
}
return 'no sales for the year'
```

However you can avoid all this by doing a combined select for everything:

```
$months = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12];
$sales = ArtistSale::query()->where('artist_id', $artist->id)
       ->whereYear('sales_date', $year)
       ->where(function ($query) use ($months) {
            foreach ($months as $month) {
                //Since months has all months this is not really needed but would be needed if you decided to remove a few months from the above array
                $query->whereMonth('sales_date', '=', $months, "or");
            }
        })->get();
 if ($sales && $sales->isNotEmpty()) {
    return $sales->groupBy(function ($sale) {
       //This assumes that you have sales date in your $dates cast fields
       return $sale->sales_date->format('M'); 
    });
 } else {
     return 'no sales for the year';
 }
```

This will do a single query and return the result grouped by month.

Answer (score 0):

You should use where on existing sales to extend the query and then call get to get results. In this way you should have only 2 queries. One for check if exists and second with wanted data.

Note:
Code is not tested please correct incorrect parts in your code.

```
 $months = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12];
 $sales = ArtistSale::where('artist_id', $artist->id)->whereYear('sales_date', $year);
 if($sales->exists()){
     foreach ($months as $month) {
         $sales->whereMonth('sales_date', $month);
     }
     return $month_sales->get();
  }
  return 'no sales for the year'
```